# sphinxsearch postgres sphinx_select disable match section

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

I use sphinx for postgres and run this query

```
SELECT id,weight FROM sphinx_select('sessionsearchsphinxidx','someword','', '', 0,50000,'ranker=wordcount')
```

I want to use this method in case when no search query is defined. So in other words I want to return all records without any filter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried leaving the query blank, the second param.

Of course the weight will be meaningless as no query to match but otherwise should work.

Comment: It's strange but it doesn't work with blank param, it selects nothing

Comment: Have you checked the sphinx query log? Does the query get thought sphinx?